# ASP MVC 4 User logout after each request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logout, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization, role-base-authorization

I'm working on Asp Mvc 4 project that is working very good on my development system, it's also working very good on my demo hosting server.
But when i upload site on client's server it ask for log in on each page. and when i log in on one page i can perform action on that page. but if it open another page it redirect me to log in page again.

I can't understand the reason. Because it works fine on my local system and also on my demo hosting. But on client hosting it behave like this.

I'm using custom Authorization Attribute. but i use this method on another site that is running very well.

any idea or solution please.

Following is me web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="AccountingSystem.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="UI.Web.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVER4;Initial Catalog=clouddms_dms_demo;Integrated Security=False;User ID=*****;Password=******;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DocumentManagerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataContext.csdl|res://*/DataContext.ssdl|res://*/DataContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SQLSERVER4;initial catalog=clouddms_dms_demo;integrated security=False;;User ID=******;Password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="microsoft.visualstudio.teamsystems.backupinfo" value="1;web.config.backup" />
    <add key="microsoft.visualstudio.teamsystems.aspnetdevserver:/" value="8804;True;7480;1;-8587902403488351008" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Error/" />
    <!--<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/InsufcientPrivilage"/>
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound"/>
    </customErrors>-->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <profile inherits="UI.Web.UserProfile" defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <!--<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>-->
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
      </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
      </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
      </entityFramework>
  <applicationSettings>
    <UI.Web.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="DataRootDir" serializeAs="String">
        <value>/Data/</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DataUserRoot" serializeAs="String">
        <value>/Data/Users/</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SiteDatalDir" serializeAs="String">
        <value>/Data/SiteData/</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="FileIconDir" serializeAs="String">
        <value>/Data/SiteData/Icons/</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ContactPicDir" serializeAs="String">
        <value>/Data/SiteData/ContactPic/</value>
      </setting>
    </UI.Web.Properties.Settings>
    <!--<UI.Web.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="DataGlobalDir" serializeAs="String">
            <value>/Data/</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="UserDataRootDir" serializeAs="String">
        <value>/Data/Company/</value>
          </setting>
      <setting name="SiteDatalDir" serializeAs="String">
        <value>/Data/Site/</value>
      </setting>
    </UI.Web.Properties.Settings>-->
      </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you automatically log out after a short period of time too?

Comment: its not matter of time. it ask me to login on each page request. if i refresh same page after login it do not redirect me to login.

Comment: Then i do think its a matter of time, try refresh the page after 10mins see what happens?

Comment: after 10 min it should logout user but immagately after log in it shoul'nt ask for login.

Comment: Without any code provided, I am only guessing where your problem is, i don't know how long your timeout is set etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many ways and also searched on internet but could not find solution. The main confusion was that same build worked on other servers. but on actual client's server i signed out user.
So i asked my client to change hosting server. AND that works.

Now on new hosting its working great..............
thanks @Eric Wang for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a machine key in your Web.config, generate one [here](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey) and place it in your Web.config file.

```
<system.web>
    place your generated machine key here
</system.web>
```

Machine key is used for: Configures algorithms and keys to use for encryption, decryption, and validation of forms-authentication data and view-state data, and for out-of-process session state identification.

Comment: But exact same code is running fine on another hosting.

Comment: @Anjum we seriously couldn't help you if you are not willing to provide any demo code